# "Files download" window in Vista Home premium

Tags: windows-vista

When we download some files from web using vista, after the download completes, there are no(as it is on Win-XP file download window) menus which says "Open", "Open containing folder"

So clicking "open" would open the recently downloaded file.

Is there any way to enable them on Win Vista Home premium?

thank you.

-AD

Answer (score 1):

**Internet Options** > **Advanced** tab > **Browsing**

check **'Notify when downloads complete'**

Comment: @Molly: This is not what i meant. What i am looking at to enable a menu on a download window which will enable me to open the file after it has been downloaded completely.

Comment: gotcha, edited my answer, sorry for the misunderstanding. i was confused by OPEN, because it actually changes to RUN when the download is complete and this is not Vista-specific but the same setting in all versions of Windows, so you might change the tag :)